# How to get the method which is handling a method call

Tags: ruby

I have an app which uses Ruby 1.8. 6 in a Rails 2.2.2 app.

It has many definitions of the method `url_for` in various parts of the code base (classes, modules etc).

When debugging, I'd like to see in the log which method handles a specific call to `url_for`. E.g.,

```
foo = "bar"
baz = url_for(foo)
#would like to log the location of the url_for method which actually 
#handled the call, here.
```

It's fine if the only way to do this is to raise an exception inside `url_for` and look at the stack trace, eg

```
baz = url_for(something_which_wont_raise_here_but_will_raise_inside_the_url_for_method)
```

To go further, what if the method is being called on an instance of a (heavily patched) class:

```
foo = @baz.bar("qux")
```

EDIT:  I didn't specify that it was Ruby 1.8.6 in my question, and it looks like i can't use the `.source_location` method.  Very sorry about not specifying the version earlier!  Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Not clear. Do you want to know where the method is defined (i.e., which method is called), or where the method is called?

Comment: This one: " where the method is defined (i.e., which method is called)"

Comment: I hope you are aware that this version of Ruby has been unmaintained for a *very* long time and contains numerous unfixed bugs, including, but not limited to, security holes.

Comment: @JörgWMittag yeah, we're working on upgrading... it is a bit embarassing.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to do

```
method(:url_for)
```

to get a [`Method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Method.html) object, and then use `source_location` to find out where it was defined

Comment: Thanks.  V sorry but just realised i don't have this method in this app's version of ruby - see my edit.

Comment: No idea sorry - it has been an extremely long time since that version was released.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `method` and `source_location` methods chain to get the location of the method definition.

For example:

[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks.  What would i do in the case that the method is being called on an object, eg `foo = @baz.bar("qux")`, and i wanted to know which `bar` method was being called?  (let's imagine @baz is an instance of a heavily patched class and it's not obvious)

Comment: @MaxWilliams You can achieve it with:  `@baz.method(:bar).source_location`

Comment: Thanks.  V sorry but just realised i don't have this method in this app's version of ruby - see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you do:

```
method(:url_for).owner
```

It will give you the module/class in which the method is defined. This should be enough to let you identify the method (unless the same method is redundantly defined in the same module multiple times). You can then look at the definition of `url_for` in that module/class.

Comment: Thanks.  V sorry but just realised i don't have this method in this app's version of ruby - see my edit.